# Use Exchange Web Service Managed API to retrieve max send mail size limit

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've been looking around for some way to use the EWS managed API to retrieve the maximum mail size limit for sending, but have not found any working solution...

So far, I've came across this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-service-configuration-information-by-using-ews-in-exchange#code-example-get-service-configuration-information-for-mail-tips-by-using-ews

Which basically retrieves the The maximum message size in the Mail Tips. But the thing is, when I tried out the code, I got an 500 internal server error. And there doesn't seem to be a way to do this directly using the Managed API itself.

Greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the Microsoft Sample they have modified the SOAP namespaces from http to https. Probably some editor thought they where doing the correct thing without understanding how XML schema's work. But a working sample is

```
        private static void GetServiceConfiguration()
    {
        // XML for the GetServiceConfiguration request SOAP envelope for mail tips configuration information.
        const string getServiceConfigurationRequest =
          "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
          "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\n" +
          "               xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages\"\n" +
          "               xmlns:t=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types\" \n" +
          "               xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\n" +
          "               xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\n" +
          "  <soap:Header>\n" +
          "    <t:RequestServerVersion Version=\"Exchange2013\" />\n" +
          "  </soap:Header>\n" +
          "  <soap:Body>\n" +
          "    <m:GetServiceConfiguration>\n" +
          "      <m:ActingAs>\n" +
          "        <t:EmailAddress>user@domain.com</t:EmailAddress>\n" +
          "        <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType>\n" +
          "      </m:ActingAs>\n" +
          "      <m:RequestedConfiguration>\n" +
          "        <m:ConfigurationName>MailTips</m:ConfigurationName>\n" +
          "      </m:RequestedConfiguration>\n" +
          "    </m:GetServiceConfiguration>\n" +
          "  </soap:Body>\n" +
          "</soap:Envelope>";
        // Encoded GetServiceConfiguration operation request.
        byte[] payload = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(getServiceConfigurationRequest);
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx");
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "blah");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(payload, 0, payload.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("You will need to parse this response to get the configuration information:\n\n" + responseFromServer);
                reader.Close();
                responseStream.Close();
            }
            else
                throw new WebException(response.StatusDescription);

        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

I've also added in a useragent as this can sometimes also cause the code to fail if useragent restriction have been set. But you should also switch to using OAuth if you are using this against Office365.

Comment: Hi Glen, 

I tried the code but it still get a 500 Internal Server Error. I can’t see the exact details of the error because apparently it’s blocked by some security policy. However, the actual Managed EWS API has no issues. So I’m thinking it might be something related to permissions or authentication… any ideas to troubleshoot? Thanks.

Comment: whats the result you get is it XML or some http error ?

Comment: It's a http error. I suspect that it's missing some additional headers within the HttpRequest. I'm now looking through the Managed EWS API to see how exactly the Http request is generated.